# Django Templates: comparing variables and assigning new variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my post model I have thumbnail and image field. when I do post.thumbnail or post.image, the image gets displayed. but when I check my admin, there's no image or thumbnail got saved. which is weird because I remember that being saved before I wrote more code. I changed few things and they don't get saved maybe...anyway I didn't bother because the image still got displayed when I did post.image.

Now I'm trying to let users be able to share any post in my website.
but here's the problem.

If I do

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
```

then, even when I posted an image and that image gets displayed with `post.image`, some default image is being shown (when I don't post any image, I made the way default image to be shown).

This is my template code:

```
{% if post.main_image %}
    <img src="{{post.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
    {{post.get_image_url }}
{% elif post.video %}
    {% video post.video as my_video %}
    <img src="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>{% endvideo %}
{% elif post.url %}
    <img src="{{post.image}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺ EBAGU" height="75" width="75"/>
{% else %}
    <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="☺" height="75" width="75"/>
{% endif %}
```

My question is: am I allowed to do

```
{{post.image}} == {{post.thumbnail}} == {{ my_video.thumbnail }}=={{post.forsharingimage}}
```

Then using it like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.forsharingimage}}" />
```

In short: setting `{{post.something}} == {{post.somethingelse}}` then using `{{post.somethingelse}}` as a variable. Is this valid?

This is how my image gets saved:

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    try:
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return random.choice(myList)

        else:
            if article.top_image.src is None:
              return random.choice(myList)
            else:
                resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
                return article.top_image.src
    except ParseError:
        if can_handle():
                handle_exception()
            else:
                print("couldn't handle exception: url={0}".format(url))
                raise


class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     def form_valid(self, form):

            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = MyProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
            self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
```

Edit: this is what I did instead, but it's not working...

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ebagu.net"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{post.title}}"/>    
<meta property="og:description" content="{{post.content|safe}}" />
<meta property="article:author" content="ebagu" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
 {% if post.main_image %}

<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.get_image_url}}" />

  {% elif post.video %}
  {% video post.video as my_video %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" />
        {% endvideo %}
  {% elif post.url %}

<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.image}}" />

{% else %}

<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.thumbnail}}" />

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Did you try? Did it work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no, because I wanted to know if it's valid first

Comment: Are you trying to assign value to a variable and then use that variable in other part of template?

Comment: @v1k45 yes that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: what do you mean by _not working_? post the full traceback (if any)

Comment: when I click share, it should show an image that's displayed in my post.html but shows different default image(image that's shown when there's no image)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question actually is because there could be several issues. First thing is that to post to a social network, the meta tags (in your case OpenGraph `og:image`) have to contain absolute URLs and this is not what Django uses. Django always works with relative URLs (even if calling `mymodel.get_absolute_url()`).

The other thing you are doing is trying to find out whether your image exists. I don't understand that part of your question at all, so I'm focusing on the meta tag problem:

---

You need to add the absolute URL as `og:image` value:

The absolute URL is returned in Django by calling `request.build_absolute_uri(path)`.

You can achieve that in the template using a templatetag like this:

```
# Change to simple_tag as of Django 1.9
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_absolute_url(context, relurl):
    if not relurl:
        return None

    request = context['request']
    return request.build_absolute_uri(relurl)
```

And in the template:

```
{% load absoluteurl %}
{% if post.main_image %}
    {% get_absolute_url post.main_image.url as image_url %}
{% endif %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ image_url }}" />
```

---

To answer this question:

> am I allowed to do

```
{{post.image}} == {{post.thumbnail}} == {{ my_video.thumbnail }}=={{post.forsharingimage}}
```

No you cannot do a comparison with more than 2 sides in templates (best is to try it with dummy data in a minimal way for yourself).

Because: `==` is a comparison with a boolean result.

But I think you really want to do an assignment: `=`
This is even less possible with more than two sides.

---

And to answer this question:

> setting {{post.something}} == {{post.somethingelse}} then using {{post.somethingelse}} as a variable. Is this valid?

No you cannot assign a boolean from a comparison result as variable in a template. You have to do that in the view and add it to the context. This does *not work*:

```
{% with 'bla' == 'bla' as test %}
===={% if 'bla' == test %} {{ test }} {% endif %}====
{% endwith %}
```

Throws:

```
TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment
```

If you do not want to compare but only assign you can do that like this:

```
{% with 'bla' as test %}
===={% if 'bla' == test %} {{ test }} {% endif %}====
{% endwith %}
```

If you have different variables (in your case images) that you want to use in the same way, you should do the assignment in an if-elif-else-block and then use the new variable in the following template code:

```
{% if large_image %}
    {% get_absolute_url large_image.image.url as image_url %}
{% elif small_image %}
    {% get_absolute_url small_image.image.url as image_url %}
{% endif %}

Do something with {{ image_url }}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand this... so I should make a new file named templatetag.py and use the code above in that file, then load that template in post.html?

Comment: Create a directory `templatetags` that contains a file `absoluteurl.py`. You can use that templatetag anywhere in your templates.

Comment: ok although I don't completely get the code, I did this; created templatetags folder and inside that folder absoluteurl.py exists. then copied the code above.

Comment: You should try to understand at least the template code. You have to replace `post.main_image.url` with the correct variable pointing to the image url.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to assign value to a variable in the templates..

You can use `with` tag to achieve it:

```
{% with myvar=post.something.special_var %}
    This is {{ myvar }}
{% endwith %}
```

Read more about with tag @ [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: can you check what I editted? that's what I did instead